# How to use the decimate modifier?

Tags: modeling

I was wondering how to use the decimate modifier. I want to take an existing 3d model and be able to reduce the vertex count on it so I can use it in a virtual table top game I'm playing with on Steam.

More than willing to put the time in to learn, but I don't know where to start.

I'll continue my search on self teaching, but I really could use someone's help.

Thank you

Comment: tutorial requests are [off topic](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/2816) , a quick search on youtube returned 10+ tutorials dedicated just for this modifier.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the forum rules and I shamelessly admit I didn't read them or even look for them. I'll try and delete this post or maybe a moderator can. Thank you

Comment: Not sure how to change the topic....keeps asking me to use an already created topic. Kind of confusing.

Comment: @Acctingman please take a couple of minutes an read through the [help] section to understand how the site works and how you can get answers through it.

Comment: Here's a link to the manual page of the decimate modifier: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html?highlight=decimate

Comment: @user2816 I use blender on Mac, which has rather unconventional shortcuts and layouts compared to the Windows version. Often times, the ramblings of small children attempting to recount something they recently discovered require constant cross-referencing. I came across this page looking for a textual explanation to avoid the "pause, find in Mac, pause, find in Mac" process. The least you could have done was post your search parameters when being facetious. It would have made your reply less useless.